# How did David and Sydney go back to normal?

Tags: marvel, legion

In the first episode of *Legion*, the main protagonist David is stuck in a mental hospital, where he meets a new patient named Sydney. Sydney's main behavioral quirk is that she doesn't like to be touched, but at one point David kisses her anyway.

This results in Sydney's power activating, and

> the two of them swapping bodies.

However, at some point in the future, when David is out of the hospital and goes to visit his sister, it's clear that things have returned to normal. The structure of the episode is very confusing -- an out-of-order jumble of flashbacks and memories, but as far as I can tell, we never see that happen. In one scene David's under the influence of Sydney's power, and the next minute he appears to be back to normal.

Is this part of the story we just haven't seen yet, or did I miss it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a limit of Sydney's power. The swap back likely happened exactly as we saw it, when David was sitting at the cafe table. Sydney makes a comment to him that "after a few hours, we swapped back". At that time, Sydney was in the car with her rescuers, who thought she was David. The next moment, their bodies had returned -- there was no contact or even proximity between Syd and David.

We finally see this happen conclusively in "Chapter 4". When Sydney swaps places with another person, the two bodies stay where they are but the minds switch places. Later on, Sydney's power somehow "turns off", and the minds remain in place but the physical bodies switch back.

In "Chapter 4" when Syndey swaps minds with

> The Eye

she is later being restrained by people who think she is her target, while that person stands (in Syd's body) several yards away. Suddenly, the two bodies swap back, but Sydney is still restrained. It's clear that her swapped body was physically replaced, exactly in-place, by her real body, and vice versa.

---

On a side note: it's not yet clear exactly when or how this second swap is triggered; it seems to happen very conveniently for Syd in "Chapter 4", but the way she describes it to David makes it sound like she has no control over it, but rather it just has a 'time limit'.

Comment: You've described the events of chapter 4, not chapter 5.  However, at some point (I think chapter 5, but could be chapter 4), David and Syd discuss their first swap.  During this conversation they reveal that the swap lasts for two hours.  The second swap seems to be a timeout thing.

Comment: you're right; I binge-watched 3-5 and got them all mixed up. I'm pretty sure Syd and David discussed their first swap in Chapter 3, though

Comment: if she had full control over the swap back, she probably would have swapped back as soon as she saw the other swapper about to commit violence on her friend. the timing a few minutes later definitely feels too convenient, though. perhaps it's something she just doesn't have proper control over.

Answer (score 0):

***SPOILERS BELOW MAYBE - but it is the first episode so it really isn't a big spoiler ***

The whole thing is a giant mind screw, what is real, what isn't real, is the ending real, David isn't even sure at the end.

[In the comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_(Marvel_Comics)), David has multiple personalities, each control a different power, so if we take everything that happened as "real", and if I had to *guess* I would say it was a power used by one of David's personalities there were left behind by the swap.

Seeing how all the damage was done to the hospital after her power activated you could take that as not all the personalities were not swapped, only the core personality did. I base this on the fact that while in Sydney's body, David was remarkably calm most of the time and didn't appear to be particularly affected by the goings on.

If you look at the Wikipedia page for that character that David is based on, the powers in the comic include being able to remake reality and time as they see fit, and each personality controls a different power, so it isn't too hard to imagine one of the personalities having the power to swap them back or if Sydney managed to control the power in the body, swap herself back using those powers.

Of course, this assumes the series follows the comics in some small way, with the personalities having different powers.

As an alternative theory, his body, containing Sydney, was captured/rescued by the "other mutants", who appear to have varying degrees of powers (as shown at the end of the episode), and they may have had the capability to undo the swap.

Or possibly, as [put by SFGate](http://www.sfgate.com/entertainment/the-wrap/article/Legion-What-s-Up-With-David-and-Syd-s-10919457.php):

> it’s possible the reason David is suddenly in his own body is because he hallucinated the whole ordeal.

Maybe, hopefully it will be explained in a later episode.

Comment: I considered the 'it was all a dream' bit but there seemed to be a _ton_ of independent confirmation that Sydney's "body" really left the hospital but David's "body" later shows up at his sister's house. But yes, maybe we'll learn more in the future.

Comment: In episode 2, we see the "other mutants" driving along with David in the car, and then suddenly they're driving along with Sydney in the car, and Sydney is like "Sorry...//shrug". So maybe her body-swapping power has a distance limit? (Assuming it *is* her power... she also thinks that she's responsible for Lenny's death, so clearly there's more going on than a switch of personalities.)

Comment: She is responsible for Lenny's death because David's power stayed with his body, but Syd's mind couldn't cope with it, so it "exploded" out of her in the hospital, including melting Lenny into a wall.